# Updating Twitter Profile Image with Twitter API V2

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I'm in the process of updating a Twitter app for API v2. In v1.1 there was an endpoint for changing a profile picture. Does a similar endpoint exist in v2? I haven't been able to find it in the documentation.